# Highchart timezones

Tags: highcharts, timezone

We are trying to show time in different zones. we made utc = false and from server we are converting it to that particular time zone. say for example to EST from system time. We are able to see the alert properly but while rendering the graph, it shows different time altogether. can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

You can disable UTC timezon in highcharts by:

```
 Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
```

and then prepare your own calculation. But you need to be aware that it depeneds on your timezones concept, because javascript has limitation of this.

Answer (score 0):

High charts supports only UTC or otherwise the timezone of the browser. You can not give your own timezone in highcharts. That is one limitation. you will have to work around that limitation some way around.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have been through this initially when I started working on Highcharts. The only option you have is to set the useUTC field correctly.

My suggestion is to convert the time to UTC  and send value in milliseconds and use "useUTC:false".